# Как изменить выпадающий список в инспекторе из кода?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу игру на юнити. Есть задача, менять значение выпадающего списка (!В инспекторе!) во время игры, из кода. Необходимо написать метод, выполняющий эту задачу. Как это реализовать? Вот код скрипта: https://pastebin.com/3MRiSF4C

[image: Скрин из инспектора]

Comment: Если это скачан с Assets Store ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО пишите что это с Assets Store. Я в  Unity могу выполнить множество задач с UI, но с assets-ами не знаком.

Comment: Скрипт с ассет стора. Но можете не беспокоиться на этот счет, проблем с доступом к скрипту не будет. Я таки объявил конкурс на тот вопрос, и проблему решил))) Считайте, что это обычный скрипт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Герман, добрый день, насколько я понимаю, вам нужно создать выпадающий список и менять его значения во время игры программно, из скрипта. В предыдущем ответе предложили сделать как-то что-то с enum. Однако перечисление enum является строго типизированным значением, что значит, что вы не можете менять его в "рантайме", то есть во время игры. Вы можете только задать сразу стартовые значения из скрипта. Перечисления - это, скажем так, константа.

Вместо этого я могу предложить вам попробовать реализовать вашу идею с помощью массива со значениями:

```
string[] modes = new string[] {"Disabled", "ClickAnywhere", "ClickOnDialog", "ClickOnButton"};
```

И простой переменной типа string:

```
string current_mode;
```

Когда нужно сменить тип, то просто сменяете:
`current_mode = modes[2];`
Или можно вообще без массива и менять напрямую:
`current_mode = "ClickOnDialog"`;

Чтобы проверить режим, используете простейшую проверку строк:

```
switch (current_mode) {
    case "Disabled": 
        // Do 1
        break;
    case ClickAnywhere:
        // Do 2
        break;
}
```

Очень надеюсь, что помог вам. Если есть какие-либо вопросы - задавайте, я обязательно отвечу. Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав на галочку.

Comment: Спасибо вам, ответ был очень исчерпывающий. Галочка заслуженно)

Comment: А можно вопрос? Написано, что вопрос имеет конкурс на 50 баллов, однако я их не получил, после того как вы поставили галочку

Comment: @МаксимФисман получите, как только истечет срок конкурса.

Comment: Буду наддеяться

Answer (score -1):

Такое выпадающее меню легко создать. В своём скрипте, где вы хотите такое реализовать создаёте перечисление enum, в нем будут содержаться элементы меню. Потом просто создаете публичный экземпляр этого перечесления. А в методе Update просто проверяете этот экземпляр.

Comment: я хочу его не создать. А изменить уже существующий, как это сделать?

Comment: Просто взять и добавить в enum значения, которые вы хотите добавить.

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, привести пример?

Comment: Нет, вы снова не так поняли. Необходимо изменить ЗНАЧЕНИЕ списка, ВО ВРЕМЯ ИГРЫ, из СКРИПТА.

Comment: То есть экземпляр перечисления с заданным по умолчанию значением и вы хотите изменить его во время игры? Или вы хотите в перечисление добавить новое значение?

Comment: Изменить во время игры, добавлять значений мне не нужно